# Floating label from chakra-ui and react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, chakra-ui

As a noobie, I have ReactSelect as a defalut component and I'm having troble implemnting a floating `label` with chakra-ui as it is demonstrated [here](https://chakra-ui.com/community/recipes/floating-labels).

Tryed to add a className="identifier" so `theme`can find my component. It kind of worked  using extendTheme over `component/index`.

`'input:not(:placeholder-shown) + label, .identifier:not(:placeholder-shown) + label...`

Happens that `label` its always active, floating top left and not transitioning back center when there is no option is selected.

If you remove imput from identifier `"input:not(:placeholder-shown) + label, .identifier:not(:placeholder-shown) + label...`

Oposit behavior.
Same doen't happen with date or text imput.

Anys sugestions?
https://codesandbox.io/embed/eager-darkness-3nh94z?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1):

I had your same problem.
I found that exist this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/chakra-react-select created to make it easier to use the full power of react-select in a chackra-ui react environment.

Here the steps to solve the issue using this package: https://github.com/csandman/chakra-react-select/issues/83

In the git issue they use CreatableSelect, but I tested that works with normal Select too (from chakra-react-select package)